# Anchoring item to center of the screen with some offset

Tags: android, view, layout-anchor

I am trying to build a screen with a chat bubble. Problem is when i use `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` the bubble gets exactly to the center and expands on both direction based on the size of text. But I want to anchor the center of this bubble 20dp right to the center of the screen or parent layout.

```
<View
                android:id="@+id/anchor"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview"
                android:text="Some Text"
                style="Style_with_layout_height_width_etc"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/anchor"
                android:layout_marginStart="-20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
```

> I have tried the methods like having an anchor view with 0dp width and height but its of no use.

EDIT-1 : added XML code for further reference

EDIT-2 : using constraint layout and setting the horizontal bias helped me solve the problem.

Comment: Please share some of your code

Comment: You can have a look at the code now @ReazMurshed

Comment: The question is still not very clear. Try adding images about what you're getting and what do you want.

Comment: In simple words, I want to fix the center of the textview to certain point on the screen. in my case, the center should be 20dp on the right of the center of the screen, that is 200dp on 360dp screen. I dont think you need image for this

Comment: Yes I still need a basic sketch of it so that I can see that how the `TextView` will look like when you have a long text in here along with a short text to see the differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the new `ConstraintLayout` for adjusting the view's position precisely for your needs.

Reference- 
https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it doesnt have option of anchoring the center

Comment: Little tinkering helped me solve the problem. Thanks a ton.